# Node js - twitter Premium search API - search for url

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I'm trying to search for `t.co` (twitters mandatory url shortening) url's using twitters Premium Search API's. Using the standard search api I can get results, but with the premium api I am having troubles.

I've been using the `twitter` npm package.

```
const Twitter = require('twitter')
const client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: '...',
  consumer_secret: '...',
  access_token_key: '...',
  access_token_secret: '...'
})
```

...this is what works calling the standard search api:

```
client.get('search/tweets', { q: 'https://t.co/ qwjhdxDp9z' }, function(error, tweets, response) {
  console.log(tweets)
})
```

...but this, using the Premium search API, fails

```
let uri = 'https://t.co/ qwjhdxDp9z'
let res = encodeURIComponent(uri)

client.get('tweets/search/fullarchive/prod', { query: uri, fromDate: '200603220000', toDate: '201910141338' }, function(error, tweets, response) {
  console.log(tweets)
})
```

I am assuming it fails dues to the url encoding, but if I don't encode the url it returns this error:

> message: 'There were errors processing your request: no viable
>   alternative at character \'/\' (at position 7), no viable alternative
>   at character \'/\' (at position 8)

Using the above approach, searching for a normal string such as `banana` works fine, it's just when searching for url's that I have issues.

`*note I have edited the twitter urls above with a space as I'm not allowed to post URL shorteners here`

UPDATE:
for structuring the above search queries, I am using info from the twitter search API documentation here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/premium-search

Comment: is the twitter module known to work with premium search?

Comment: @AndyPiper it works when searching for strings such as `banana`... but you're right - on closer inspection the module's last publish was 2 years ago, so maybe premium search isn't supported

Comment: I was fairly sure that the syntax for premium search wasn’t yet integrated into that module unfortunately.

Comment: that's a shame but good to know, thanks @AndyPiper. From what I can see there is no node modules that do support premium search?

Comment: This GitHub project may be useful? https://github.com/joeywhelan/twitterSearch